# Can I convert a 30A sub-panel to a regular 120 circuit?

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I have a small 30A sub-panel that once powered a green house, some lights and 1 regular 120V outlet. We have since removed the greenhouse and it's associated wiring and now the sub panel is an eyesore and in an unsafe location as it is low at outlet height in a finished basement family room and I was always worried a child could easily access it.
It now only feeds 2 breakers which are powering 6 recessed LED lights and one standard 120V receptacle in my interior finished basement.
We are renovating and I would like to remove the sub panel and just replace it with an outlet.

My plan:

Take the 10/2 wire in the main service panel off the 30-amp double breaker and put it on a single pole 15 amp breaker, putting white on the neutral and black on the new breaker, ground is still ground.

Rip out the old sub-panel and replace it with a square junction box and put a one or 2 gang mud ring on it for the outlet or outlets, depending on box size needed.

I would splice the 2 existing circuits and the 10-awg wire with a pigtail for the new outlet. Everything would be 120V now.

I would use a single pole 15A breaker as there is some 14 gauge wire in the circuits for the lights and I am sizing the breaker down to the smallest gauge wire.

I know this sounds like a lot, but it really isn't and I could remove this ugly sub panel that was put in my finished basement while we renovate.

Does this sound like a proper plan?

Comment: That is a sound plan in my mind.

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me, but I'm not familiar with US codes.  I'd put a note in the main panel that the circuit contains 14-gauge wire so that a future owner (or even a future you) isn't tempted to replace the breaker with a bigger one at some point in the future.

Comment: Your concern about children accessing panels has me concerned about code compliance with your panels.  There are 2 reasons I would not want a child near a panel: a) the deadfront cover has been removed and many hot things are in reach. Or b) a twist-out has been removed and there is no circuit breaker or blanking cover there, leaving an open gap for curious fingers.  Both of those are code violations and should not be tolerated. The best hole filler is a breaker!

Comment: It's a good inference.   The box is low at around 24 inches.    It can be locked and I leave it that way.   However when it is opened the breakers are terribly loose.   I don't think this was a good location for a sub panel, regardless of whether it really can't be accessed.   Accidents happen, and leaving the lock off in a momentary lapse leaves it way to easy to open and those breakers are really jiggly.   It's really a moot point because I am not advocating for the sub panel to stay, but for it to be removed and made safer.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a good plan. Is there any chance you can replace the #14 AWG with #12 AWG? You might want to add more outlets in the future and if any new outlets added in any unfinished parts would need to be GFCI.  There should be no problem fitting #10 into a 15 amp breaker in the main panel. If there is, pigtail a piece of #14 to the #10 and run the #14 into the breaker.

Comment: Thx.  I would replace the wire if I could, but think it would be too destructive as they are stapled behind sheet rock ceilings I don't want to open up.   Anyway, I have other 20 amp circuts in the basement and specific dedicated ones in the unfinished part of the basement with GFCI protection. I won't ever add onto this circuit, I would run new ones and/or add the others that are 20 amp.

Comment: Good call about the note in the main, so no one is tempted to size up the breaker, I agree and thx!!